# PHP Send Array Data via Email

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, email

Using PHP I am posting an array of form inputs to a database, then sending this data via email.

The variable `$mac_address_array = $_POST['MacAddress']` is an indexed array.

A `print_r($_POST)` displays the following;

```
[MacAddress] => Array
    (
        [0] => 333
        [1] => 444
    )
```

I would like to send this data via email, formatted on separate lines if possible. My email script works, however only when I use the following code in my email script;

```
mail($recipient, $subject, print_r( $mac_address_array, true ), $headers);
```

I successfully receive the email, but values are displayed like this;

```
Subject,

Array ( [0] => 333 [1] => 444 )
```

Is there any way I can display them like this;

```
Subject,

- MAC Address 1: 333
- MAC Address 2: 444
```

I know I need a `foreach` loop somewhere, this is where I'm stuck!

Any advice is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```html
$addressesAsString = '';
foreach ($mac_address_array as $key => $value) {
    $addressesAsString .= '- Mac Address '.($key+1).': '.$value.PHP_EOL;
}
```

Comment: @TheOrdinaryGeek I did not see your foreach loop, I can not say what you were doing wrong. You provided just `print_r()` that prints info about array, you weren't iterating over it. read the docs, it would help